# Program compiles, but no output is being generated

Tags: c++11

Essentially after running all of the below code, I'm aiming to output a single element of my Countries vector just to test and see if I'm actually populating it or not. Nothing is outputting though, no errors are met and If I screwed something up I have no clue how to go about fixing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Country {

 string Name;
 string Population;
 string Area;
 string Density;
 string Migration;
 string GDP;
 string Literacy;
 string Birthrate;

};

int main(){

 ifstream data ("countries.csv");

 vector<Country> Countries;

 while (data.good()){

  Country temp;


  getline(data, temp.Name, ',');
  getline(data, temp.Population, ',');
  getline(data, temp.Area, ',');
  getline(data, temp.Density, ',');
  getline(data, temp.Migration, ',');
  getline(data, temp.GDP, ',');
  getline(data, temp.Literacy, ',');
  getline(data, temp.Birthrate, '\n');

  Countries.push_back(temp);

 }

 Country c1 = Countries[1];
 Country c2 = Countries[2];

 cout << c1.Name << ", " << c1.Population << ", " << c1.Area << ", "           
      << c1.Density << ", " << c1.Migration << ", " << c1.GDP << ", "
      << c1.Literacy << ", " << c1.Birthrate << endl;
 cout << c2.Name << ", " << c2.Population << ", " << c2.Area << ", "           
      << c2.Density << ", " << c2.Migration << ", " << c2.GDP << ", "
      << c2.Literacy << ", " << c2.Birthrate << endl;

 return 0;

}
```

This is the file in which I get the data

```
#Country,Population,Area (sq. mi.),Pop. Density (per sq. mi.),Net migration,GDP ($ per capita),Literacy (%),Birthrate
Afghanistan ,31056997,647500,48,23.06,700,36,46.6
Albania ,3581655,28748,124.6,-4.93,4500,86.5,15.11
Algeria ,32930091,2381740,13.8,-0.39,6000,70,17.14
American Samoa ,57794,199,290.4,-20.71,8000,97,22.46
Andorra ,71201,468,152.1,6.6,19000,100,8.71
Angola ,12127071,1246700,9.7,0,1900,42,45.11
Anguilla ,13477,102,132.1,10.76,8600,95,14.17
Antigua & Barbuda ,69108,443,156,-6.15,11000,89,16.93
Argentina ,39921833,2766890,14.4,0.61,11200,97.1,16.73
Armenia ,2976372,29800,99.9,-6.47,3500,98.6,12.07
Aruba ,71891,193,372.5,0,28000,97,11.03
Australia ,20264082,7686850,2.6,3.98,29000,100,12.14
Austria ,8192880,83870,97.7,2,30000,98,8.74
Azerbaijan ,7961619,86600,91.9,-4.9,3400,97,20.74
Bahamas. The ,303770,13940,21.8,-2.2,16700,95.6,17.57
Bahrain ,698585,665,1050.5,1.05,16900,89.1,17.8
Bangladesh ,147365352,144000,1023.4,-0.71,1900,43.1,29.8
Barbados ,279912,431,649.5,-0.31,15700,97.4,12.71
Belarus ,10293011,207600,49.6,2.54,6100,99.6,11.16
Belgium ,10379067,30528,340,1.23,29100,98,10.38
Belize ,287730,22966,12.5,0,4900,94.1,28.84
Benin ,7862944,112620,69.8,0,1100,40.9,38.85
Bermuda ,65773,53,1241,2.49,36000,98,11.4
Bhutan ,2279723,47000,48.5,0,1300,42.2,33.65
Bolivia ,8989046,1098580,8.2,-1.32,2400,87.2,23.3
Bosnia & Herzegovina ,4498976,51129,88,0.31,6100,,8.77
Botswana ,1639833,600370,2.7,0,9000,79.8,23.08
Brazil ,188078227,8511965,22.1,-0.03,7600,86.4,16.56
British Virgin Is. ,23098,153,151,10.01,16000,97.8,14.89
Brunei ,379444,5770,65.8,3.59,18600,93.9,18.79
Bulgaria ,7385367,110910,66.6,-4.58,7600,98.6,9.65
Burkina Faso ,13902972,274200,50.7,0,1100,26.6,45.62
Burma ,47382633,678500,69.8,-1.8,1800,85.3,17.91
Burundi ,8090068,27830,290.7,-0.06,600,51.6,42.22
Cambodia ,13881427,181040,76.7,0,1900,69.4,26.9
Cameroon ,17340702,475440,36.5,0,1800,79,33.89
Canada ,33098932,9984670,3.3,5.96,29800,97,10.78
Cape Verde ,420979,4033,104.4,-12.07,1400,76.6,24.87
Cayman Islands ,45436,262,173.4,18.75,35000,98,12.74
Central African Rep. ,4303356,622984,6.9,0,1100,51,33.91
Chad ,9944201,1284000,7.7,-0.11,1200,47.5,45.73
Chile ,16134219,756950,21.3,0,9900,96.2,15.23
China ,1313973713,9596960,136.9,-0.4,5000,90.9,13.25
Colombia ,43593035,1138910,38.3,-0.31,6300,92.5,20.48
Comoros ,690948,2170,318.4,0,700,56.5,36.93
Congo. Dem. Rep. ,62660551,2345410,26.7,0,700,65.5,43.69
Congo. Repub. of the ,3702314,342000,10.8,-0.17,700,83.8,42.57
Cook Islands ,21388,240,89.1,,5000,95,21
Costa Rica ,4075261,51100,79.8,0.51,9100,96,18.32
Cote d'Ivoire ,17654843,322460,54.8,-0.07,1400,50.9,35.11
Croatia ,4494749,56542,79.5,1.58,10600,98.5,9.61
Cuba ,11382820,110860,102.7,-1.58,2900,97,11.89
Cyprus ,784301,9250,84.8,0.43,19200,97.6,12.56
Czech Republic ,10235455,78866,129.8,0.97,15700,99.9,9.02
Denmark ,5450661,43094,126.5,2.48,31100,100,11.13
Djibouti ,486530,23000,21.2,0,1300,67.9,39.53
Dominica ,68910,754,91.4,-13.87,5400,94,15.27
Dominican Republic ,9183984,48730,188.5,-3.22,6000,84.7,23.22
East Timor ,1062777,15007,70.8,0,500,58.6,26.99
Ecuador ,13547510,283560,47.8,-8.58,3300,92.5,22.29
Egypt ,78887007,1001450,78.8,-0.22,4000,57.7,22.94
El Salvador ,6822378,21040,324.3,-3.74,4800,80.2,26.61
Equatorial Guinea ,540109,28051,19.3,0,2700,85.7,35.59
Eritrea ,4786994,121320,39.5,0,700,58.6,34.33
Estonia ,1324333,45226,29.3,-3.16,12300,99.8,10.04
Ethiopia ,74777981,1127127,66.3,0,700,42.7,37.98
Faroe Islands ,47246,1399,33.8,1.41,22000,,14.05
Fiji ,905949,18270,49.6,-3.14,5800,93.7,22.55
Finland ,5231372,338145,15.5,0.95,27400,100,10.45
France ,60876136,547030,111.3,0.66,27600,99,11.99
French Guiana ,199509,91000,2.2,6.27,8300,83,20.46
French Polynesia ,274578,4167,65.9,2.94,17500,98,16.68
Gabon ,1424906,267667,5.3,0,5500,63.2,36.16
Gambia. The ,1641564,11300,145.3,1.57,1700,40.1,39.37
Gaza Strip ,1428757,360,3968.8,1.6,600,,39.45
Georgia ,4661473,69700,66.9,-4.7,2500,99,10.41
Germany ,82422299,357021,230.9,2.18,27600,99,8.25
Ghana ,22409572,239460,93.6,-0.64,2200,74.8,30.52
Gibraltar ,27928,7,3989.7,0,17500,,10.74
Greece ,10688058,131940,81,2.35,20000,97.5,9.68
Greenland ,56361,2166086,0,-8.37,20000,,15.93
Grenada ,89703,344,260.8,-13.92,5000,98,22.08
Guadeloupe ,452776,1780,254.4,-0.15,8000,90,15.05
Guam ,171019,541,316.1,0,21000,99,18.79
Guatemala ,12293545,108890,112.9,-1.67,4100,70.6,29.88
Guernsey ,65409,78,838.6,3.84,20000,,8.81
Guinea ,9690222,245857,39.4,-3.06,2100,35.9,41.76
Guinea-Bissau ,1442029,36120,39.9,-1.57,800,42.4,37.22
Guyana ,767245,214970,3.6,-2.07,4000,98.8,18.28
Haiti ,8308504,27750,299.4,-3.4,1600,52.9,36.44
Honduras ,7326496,112090,65.4,-1.99,2600,76.2,28.24
Hong Kong ,6940432,1092,6355.7,5.24,28800,93.5,7.29
Hungary ,9981334,93030,107.3,0.86,13900,99.4,9.72
Iceland ,299388,103000,2.9,2.38,30900,99.9,13.64
India ,1095351995,3287590,333.2,-0.07,2900,59.5,22.01
Indonesia ,245452739,1919440,127.9,0,3200,87.9,20.34
Iran ,68688433,1648000,41.7,-0.84,7000,79.4,17
Iraq ,26783383,437072,61.3,0,1500,40.4,31.98
Ireland ,4062235,70280,57.8,4.99,29600,98,14.45
Isle of Man ,75441,572,131.9,5.36,21000,,11.05
Israel ,6352117,20770,305.8,0.68,19800,95.4,17.97
Italy ,58133509,301230,193,2.07,26700,98.6,8.72
Jamaica ,2758124,10991,250.9,-4.92,3900,87.9,20.82
Japan ,127463611,377835,337.4,0,28200,99,9.37
Jersey ,91084,116,785.2,2.76,24800,,9.3
Jordan ,5906760,92300,64,6.59,4300,91.3,21.25
Kazakhstan ,15233244,2717300,5.6,-3.35,6300,98.4,16
Kenya ,34707817,582650,59.6,-0.1,1000,85.1,39.72
Kiribati ,105432,811,130,0,800,,30.65
Korea. North ,23113019,120540,191.8,0,1300,99,15.54
Korea. South ,48846823,98480,496,0,17800,97.9,10
Kuwait ,2418393,17820,135.7,14.18,19000,83.5,21.94
Kyrgyzstan ,5213898,198500,26.3,-2.45,1600,97,22.8
Laos ,6368481,236800,26.9,0,1700,66.4,35.49
Latvia ,2274735,64589,35.2,-2.23,10200,99.8,9.24
Lebanon ,3874050,10400,372.5,0,4800,87.4,18.52
Lesotho ,2022331,30355,66.6,-0.74,3000,84.8,24.75
Liberia ,3042004,111370,27.3,0,1000,57.5,44.77
Libya ,5900754,1759540,3.4,0,6400,82.6,26.49
Liechtenstein ,33987,160,212.4,4.85,25000,100,10.21
Lithuania ,3585906,65200,55,-0.71,11400,99.6,8.75
Luxembourg ,474413,2586,183.5,8.97,55100,100,11.94
Macau ,453125,28,16183,4.86,19400,94.5,8.48
Macedonia ,2050554,25333,80.9,-1.45,6700,,12.02
Madagascar ,18595469,587040,31.7,0,800,68.9,41.41
Malawi ,13013926,118480,109.8,0,600,62.7,43.13
Malaysia ,24385858,329750,74,0,9000,88.7,22.86
Maldives ,359008,300,1196.7,0,3900,97.2,34.81
Mali ,11716829,1240000,9.5,-0.33,900,46.4,49.82
Malta ,400214,316,1266.5,2.07,17700,92.8,10.22
Marshall Islands ,60422,11854,5.1,-6.04,1600,93.7,33.05
Martinique ,436131,1100,396.5,-0.05,14400,97.7,13.74
Mauritania ,3177388,1030700,3.1,0,1800,41.7,40.99
Mauritius ,1240827,2040,608.3,-0.9,11400,85.6,15.43
Mayotte ,201234,374,538.1,6.78,2600,,40.95
Mexico ,107449525,1972550,54.5,-4.87,9000,92.2,20.69
Micronesia. Fed. St. ,108004,702,153.9,-20.99,2000,89,24.68
Moldova ,4466706,33843,132,-0.26,1800,99.1,15.7
Monaco ,32543,2,16271.5,7.75,27000,99,9.19
Mongolia ,2832224,1564116,1.8,0,1800,97.8,21.59
Montserrat ,9439,102,92.5,0,3400,97,17.59
Morocco ,33241259,446550,74.4,-0.98,4000,51.7,21.98
Mozambique ,19686505,801590,24.6,0,1200,47.8,35.18
Namibia ,2044147,825418,2.5,0,7200,84,24.32
Nauru ,13287,21,632.7,0,5000,,24.76
Nepal ,28287147,147181,192.2,0,1400,45.2,30.98
Netherlands ,16491461,41526,397.1,2.91,28600,99,10.9
Netherlands Antilles ,221736,960,231,-0.41,11400,96.7,14.78
New Caledonia ,219246,19060,11.5,0,15000,91,18.11
New Zealand ,4076140,268680,15.2,4.05,21600,99,13.76
Nicaragua ,5570129,129494,43,-1.22,2300,67.5,24.51
Niger ,12525094,1267000,9.9,-0.67,800,17.6,50.73
Nigeria ,131859731,923768,142.7,0.26,900,68,40.43
N. Mariana Islands ,82459,477,172.9,9.61,12500,97,19.43
Norway ,4610820,323802,14.2,1.74,37800,100,11.46
Oman ,3102229,212460,14.6,0.28,13100,75.8,36.24
Pakistan ,165803560,803940,206.2,-2.77,2100,45.7,29.74
Palau ,20579,458,44.9,2.85,9000,92,18.03
Panama ,3191319,78200,40.8,-0.91,6300,92.6,21.74
Papua New Guinea ,5670544,462840,12.3,0,2200,64.6,29.36
Paraguay ,6506464,406750,16,-0.08,4700,94,29.1
Peru ,28302603,1285220,22,-1.05,5100,90.9,20.48
Philippines ,89468677,300000,298.2,-1.5,4600,92.6,24.89
Poland ,38536869,312685,123.3,-0.49,11100,99.8,9.85
Portugal ,10605870,92391,114.8,3.57,18000,93.3,10.72
Puerto Rico ,3927188,13790,284.8,-1.46,16800,94.1,12.77
Qatar ,885359,11437,77.4,16.29,21500,82.5,15.56
Reunion ,787584,2517,312.9,0,5800,88.9,18.9
Romania ,22303552,237500,93.9,-0.13,7000,98.4,10.7
Russia ,142893540,17075200,8.4,1.02,8900,99.6,9.95
Rwanda ,8648248,26338,328.4,0,1300,70.4,40.37
Saint Helena ,7502,413,18.2,0,2500,97,12.13
Saint Kitts & Nevis ,39129,261,149.9,-7.11,8800,97,18.02
Saint Lucia ,168458,616,273.5,-2.67,5400,67,19.68
St Pierre & Miquelon ,7026,242,29,-4.86,6900,99,13.52
St Vincent & Grenadines ,117848,389,303,-7.64,2900,96,16.18
Samoa ,176908,2944,60.1,-11.7,5600,99.7,16.43
San Marino ,29251,61,479.5,10.98,34600,96,10.02
Sao Tome & Principe ,193413,1001,193.2,-2.72,1200,79.3,40.25
Saudi Arabia ,27019731,1960582,13.8,-2.71,11800,78.8,29.34
Senegal ,11987121,196190,61.1,0.2,1600,40.2,32.78
Serbia ,9396411,88361,106.3,-1.33,2200,93,
Seychelles ,81541,455,179.2,-5.69,7800,58,16.03
Sierra Leone ,6005250,71740,83.7,0,500,31.4,45.76
Singapore ,4492150,693,6482.2,11.53,23700,92.5,9.34
Slovakia ,5439448,48845,111.4,0.3,13300,,10.65
Slovenia ,2010347,20273,99.2,1.12,19000,99.7,8.98
Solomon Islands ,552438,28450,19.4,0,1700,,30.01
Somalia ,8863338,637657,13.9,5.37,500,37.8,45.13
South Africa ,44187637,1219912,36.2,-0.29,10700,86.4,18.2
Spain ,40397842,504782,80,0.99,22000,97.9,10.06
Sri Lanka ,20222240,65610,308.2,-1.31,3700,92.3,15.51
Sudan ,41236378,2505810,16.5,-0.02,1900,61.1,34.53
Suriname ,439117,163270,2.7,-8.81,4000,93,18.02
Swaziland ,1136334,17363,65.5,0,4900,81.6,27.41
Sweden ,9016596,449964,20,1.67,26800,99,10.27
Switzerland ,7523934,41290,182.2,4.05,32700,99,9.71
Syria ,18881361,185180,102,0,3300,76.9,27.76
Taiwan ,23036087,35980,640.3,0,23400,96.1,12.56
Tajikistan ,7320815,143100,51.2,-2.86,1000,99.4,32.65
Tanzania ,37445392,945087,39.6,-2.06,600,78.2,37.71
Thailand ,64631595,514000,125.7,0,7400,92.6,13.87
Togo ,5548702,56785,97.7,0,1500,60.9,37.01
Tonga ,114689,748,153.3,0,2200,98.5,25.37
Trinidad & Tobago ,1065842,5128,207.9,-10.83,9500,98.6,12.9
Tunisia ,10175014,163610,62.2,-0.57,6900,74.2,15.52
Turkey ,70413958,780580,90.2,0,6700,86.5,16.62
Turkmenistan ,5042920,488100,10.3,-0.86,5800,98,27.61
Turks & Caicos Is ,21152,430,49.2,11.68,9600,98,21.84
Tuvalu ,11810,26,454.2,0,1100,,22.18
Uganda ,28195754,236040,119.5,0,1400,69.9,47.35
Ukraine ,46710816,603700,77.4,-0.39,5400,99.7,8.82
United Arab Emirates ,2602713,82880,31.4,1.03,23200,77.9,18.96
United Kingdom ,60609153,244820,247.6,2.19,27700,99,10.71
United States ,298444215,9631420,31,3.41,37800,97,14.14
Uruguay ,3431932,176220,19.5,-0.32,12800,98,13.91
Uzbekistan ,27307134,447400,61,-1.72,1700,99.3,26.36
Vanuatu ,208869,12200,17.1,0,2900,53,22.72
Venezuela ,25730435,912050,28.2,-0.04,4800,93.4,18.71
Vietnam ,84402966,329560,256.1,-0.45,2500,90.3,16.86
Virgin Islands ,108605,1910,56.9,-8.94,17200,,13.96
Wallis and Futuna ,16025,274,58.5,,3700,50,
West Bank ,2460492,5860,419.9,2.98,800,,31.67
Western Sahara ,273008,266000,1,,,,
Yemen ,21456188,527970,40.6,0,800,50.2,42.89
Zambia ,11502010,752614,15.3,0,800,80.6,41
Zimbabwe ,12236805,390580,31.3,0,1900,90.7,28.01
```

Comment: Please add the contents of the input file to your post.

Comment: You should show us also the content of `"countries.cvs"`; anyway, take in count that the first `Countries` elements is `Countries[0]`, not `Countries[1]`.

Comment: @RSahu file is added

Comment: Suggestion: try removing the first line from cvs

Comment: I get output working as is, is your file named correctly?  Otherwise try copying the contents in a few file, it may be corrupt.

Comment: @jman Well, thanks for giving me the heads up. Feel like punching a wall now but yeah, file was corrupt :/